# QGIS - Layer missing polygons after pointsfile transformation

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, grass-gis, georeferencing

I'm using pointsfile transformation in QGIS for the georeferentiation of my layers. After the transformation the result some times has polygons missing like here:

[image]

Why is this happening? How do I prevent it?

Comment: Perhaps check whether the polygons are valid in the input data.